# how to regex a list of url paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of url paths:

```
WHITELIST_PATHS = [ '/assets', '/images', '/javascripts']
```

How can regex be used to do something like:

```
allow_access = WHITELIST_PATHS.include? '/assets/application.css'
```

Idea being that the tested path just needs to start with a whitelist path. Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
allow_access = WHITELIST_PATHS.any? {|p| '/assets/application.css'.start_with? p }
```

Comment: Thanks, would you mind explaining how that works ? curious to learn and I'll give points !

Comment: @ColdTree [`any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500) returns true/false if any of the items in the array satisfy the block. So it will pass each path (`/assets`, `/images`, `/javascripts`) into the block as `p` in turn. The block just checks if `/assets/application.css` starts with that path. So if any of the paths match, it will return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHITELIST_PATHS = [ '/assets', '/images', '/javascripts']
# probably should be 
# WHITELIST_PATHS = [ '/assets/', '/images/', '/javascripts/']
WHITELIST_REGEXP = /^(#{WHITELIST_PATHS.join("|")})/

allow_access = !!('/assets/application.css' =~ WHITELIST_REGEXP)
```